# im trying to create a simple data base for my system but im receiving ang error #1064 i have a lot of head scratching and still no solution

Tags: database, xampp, mysql-error-1064

```sql
CREATE TABLE `users`. (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
    `username` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , 
    `email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , 
    `user_type` VARCHAR NOT NULL , 
    `password` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , 
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) 
    ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: There should be no dot after \`users\`